# Conditional ngModel data binding

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel, angular-forms

I have a problem with conditional data binding by ngModel in Angular4.

To explain:

I have a little form:

```
<form-question-radio
  [(ngModel)]="model['q4']"
  name="question"
  [options]="[{value:true, label:'Yes'}, {value:false,label:'No'}]"
  required>
      Do you want?
</form-question-radio>

<ng-container *ngIf="model['q4'] == true">
  <form-question-radio
    [(ngModel)]="model['q4_1']"
    name="question4_1"
    [options]="[
      {value:1,label:'Freedom'},
      {value:2,label:'Peace'},
      {value:3,label:'Money'}
    ]" required>
      What do you want?
  </form-question-radio>
</ng-container>
```

form-question-radio is my custom form control (implements *ControlValueAccessor*)

I would like to pass value to *model['q4_1']* only when answer for first question has **true** value. If answer for first question (*model['q4']*) has **false**, *model['q4_1']* would be **null.**

The problem starts when I check true answer for first question, afterwards check some answer for second question and i check (again) false anwer for first question. I would like the *model['q4_1']* value to be equal null, but isn't.

---

I was trying use conditional binding like:

```
[(ngModel)]="model['q4'] == true ? model['q4_1'] : null"
```

but it caused error.

---

I was trying

```
[(ngModel)]="model['q4'] && model['q4_1']"
```

too. But it still doesn't work, because returns boolean I guess. Is it?

---

**Question:**
Is there a way to conditional data binding by ngModel? How it should look like?

Answer (score 2):

**First solution:**

Use ngModelChange. It's an event that by default always writes new value into the model when the input value changes, but it can be overridden. It will be automatically emitted for every component that uses ngModel so you don't have to worry about that.

In template:

```
<form-question-radio
  [ngModel]="model['q4_1']"
  (ngModelChange)="questionQ4Change($event)">
</form-question-radio>
<form-question-radio
  [ngModel]="model['q4_1']"
  (ngModelChange)="questionQ41Change($event)">
</form-question-radio>
```

In controller:

```
questionQ4Change(newValue) {
  this.model['q4'] = newValue;
  if (!newValue) {
    this.model['q4_1'] = null;
  }
}
questionQ41Change(newValue) {
  this.model['q4_1'] = this.model['q4'] ? newValue : null;
}
```

---

**Second solution:**

You can also use getters and setters for q4 and q_1.

In template:

```
<form-question-radio
  [(ngModel)]="model['q4_1']"
</form-question-radio>
<form-question-radio
  [(ngModel)]="model['q4_1']"
</form-question-radio>
```

In controller:

```
model = {
  q_4_value: null,
  q4_1_value: null,

  get q_4() { 
    return this.q_4_value;
  },
  get q4_1() {
    return this.q4_1;
  },

  set q_4(newValue) { 
    this.q_4_value = newValue;
    if (!newValue) {
      this.q4_1_value = null;
    }
  },
  set q4_1(newValue) {
    this.q4_1_value = this.q_4 ? newValue : null;
  },
}
```

Comment: it's not solution for me. It's still changing when I change q4_1, but I have to change q4_1 value when q4 is false/true. I can understand how your solution works but i'm looking for generic solution, if you know what i mean

Comment: Okay then, you can use another questionQ4Change event, and in this event you can both set q4 new value and, if needed, change q4_1 value.

Comment: I added another solution with setters, although I think it's more complicated.